# mysql update script not updating database

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have an update query that is not updating the database.  I have verified that the if condition is meet, and verified that the data is getting posted.  I believe it is a syntax error, but I cna not see it.  Can anyone see any mistakes?

```
if(isset($_POST['account_id']) && isset($_POST['account_id']) !="") {
    $request_id  = $_POST['request_id'];
    $account_id = $_POST['account_id'];
    $class_id = $_POST['class_id'];
    $sub_account_id = $_POST['sub_account_id'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $justification = $_POST['justification'];
    $last_edited_by_uid = $_POST['last_edited_by_uid'];
    $last_edited_date = $_POST['last_edited_date'];
    try{
        $stmt3 = $db->prepare("UPDATE budget_request SET account_id=:account_id, class_id=:class_id, sub_account_id=:sub_account_id, amount=:amount, justification=:justification, last_edited_by_uid=:last_edited_by_uid, last_edited_date=:last_edited_date WHERE request_id=:request_id");
        $stmt3->bindParam(':request_id',$request_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt3->bindParam(':class_id',$class_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt3->bindParam(':account_id',$account_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt3->bindParam(':sub_account_id',$sub_account_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt3->bindParam(':amount',$amount,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt3->bindParam(':justification',$justification,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt3->bindParam(':last_edited_by_uid',$last_edited_by_uid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt3->bindParam(':last_edited_date',$last_edited_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt3->execute();
        header(sprintf('Location: budget_worksheet.php?class_id='.$class_id));    
        exit();
}
    catch(PDOException $e){
        //$db->rollBack();
        //echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }   
}
```

Comment: *I believe it’s a syntax error* : does a PDO error happen when the code executes ?

Comment: I get no error message.  The paGe loads blank and does not redirect.

Comment: You seem to catch errors but not do anything with them. Do you get a result in the page if you uncomment this : //echo $e->getMessage(); ?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I had typed a variable incorrectly all the way through.